# How do I replace an abstract method with an interface method?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I have a couple java files in a `package stacks` package.

The first one is an `abstract class Stack` class that has a `public abstract void print()` method in it.

The second one is a `public interface FancilyPrint` interface that has a `void fancyPrint()` method in it.

I am now working on a `public class LinkedListStack extends Stack implements FancyPrint` class.

How do I write a `fancyPrint()` method that satisfies the interface contract, without writing a useless `void print()` method from the abstract class? It is useless to have a standard `print()` method in this class due to it implementing the interface with its own `fancyPrint()` method. I don't remember how to do this.

Here are my classes for reference:

Stack.java:

```
package stacks;

public abstract class Stack<AnyType>
{
    public abstract void push(AnyType data);

    public abstract AnyType pop();

    public abstract AnyType peek();

    public abstract boolean isFull();

    public abstract boolean isEmpty();

    public abstract void print();
}
```

LinkedListStack.java

```
package stacks;

import linkedlists.*;

public class LinkedListStack<SomeType> extends Stack<SomeType> implements FancyPrint
{
    LinkedList<SomeType> l = new LinkedList<>();
    
    @Override
    public void push(SomeType data)
    {
        l.head_insert(data);
    }

    @Override
    public SomeType pop()
    {
        return l.delete_head();
    }

    @Override
    public SomeType peek()
    {
        return l.headData();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFull()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return l.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void fancyPrint()
    {
        
    }

    // I do not need this method for this class. I will need it for other classes
    // that extend the Stack abstract class.
    @Override
    public void print()
    {

    }
```

FancilyPrint Interface:

```
package stacks;

public interface FancilyPrint
{
    void fancyPrint();
}
```

Comment: I guess I can call the 'fancyPrint()' method from the 'print()' method. Is this the only  way to satisfy both the abstract class and the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should exclude `print` method from `Stack` class and create one more interface `SimplePrintable` having `print` method. So `LinkedListStack` will implement `FancyPrintable` but other classes will implement `SimplePrintable`.

Answer (score 2):

Create and implementation for each print procedure.

```java
interface Print {
    void print();
}

class BasicPrint implements Print {
    @Override
    public void print() {

    }
}

class FancilyPrint implements Print {
    @Override
    public void print() {

    }
}
```

Then, choose whether *Stack* should implement *BasicPrint*, or *FancilyPrint*.

```java
abstract class Stack extends BasicPrint { }
class LinkedListStack extends Stack { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what others have said I would remove the print() method from the Stack abstract class and have it in a separate interface. But I would then change the print method to take the stack it should print.

```
interface StackPrinter {
  void print(Stack stack);
}
```

Then you can have implementations for SimpleStackPrinter, FancyStackPrinter and whatever others are needed and because its not part of the Stack class anymore any stack can be passed to any printer.

Answer (score 0):

I know I can call the `fancyPrint()` method from the `print()` method. That is the only thing I can think of.